# Store notes with Async Storage in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage

I'm developing a Notes App and I want to save the notes in the device's memory. I'm using Async Storage, but without success. I create notes and they are displayed correctly until I reload the app, and they're gone.

Here is the logic to save and retrieve the notes with Async Storage:

```
async function saveNotes() {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(notes)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@notesApp' ,jsonValue)
    }
    catch(e){
      alert(e)
    }
  }

  async function getNotes() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@notesApp')
      if(value !== null){
        const notesJson = JSON.parse(value)
        notesJson.map((item: INotes) => {
          dispatch(getId(Number(item.id)))
          dispatch(titlePicker(item.title))
          dispatch(notePicker(item.note))
          dispatch(addNote())
        })
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      alert(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    saveNotes()
  }, [notes])

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes()
  }, [])
```

And here's the code of my reducers:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

export interface INotes {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  note: string,
}

const initialState = {
  noteId: 0,
  noteTitle: '',
  noteContent: '',
  notes: [] as INotes[],
}

export const notePickerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notePicker',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    idPicker: (state) => {
      state.noteId++
    },
    getId: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.noteId = action.payload
    },
    titlePicker: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.noteTitle = action.payload
    },
    notePicker: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.noteContent = action.payload
    },
    addNote: (state) => {
      state.notes = [
        ...state.notes,
        {
          id: state.noteId,
          title: state.noteTitle,
          note: state.noteContent,
        }
      ]
    },
    updateNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.notes[action.payload - 1].title = state.noteTitle
      state.notes[action.payload - 1].note = state.noteContent
    },
  }
})

export const { getId, updateNote, addNote, idPicker, titlePicker, notePicker } = notePickerSlice.actions
export default notePickerSlice.reducer
```

The github repo: (https://github.com/victorcff/Notes-App)

I don't understand why this is not working. Can someone help me?